# Xalan+ XSLT+ JAVA

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

My  xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:good="xalan://com.epam.laba.model.Good"
xmlns:validator="xalan://com.epam.laba.validator.ValidatorXslGood">

    <xsl:include href="parameter.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="validator"/>
    <xsl:param name="good"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/|node()|@*">
        <xsl:if test="validator:validateGood($good)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

......

Java code where create validator and set to xsl

```
    Good good=fillGood(parameters); 
    ValidatorXslGood validatorXslGood=new ValidatorXslGood();
    Source sourceXSL = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(sourceXSL);
    transformer.setParameter(SUBCATEGORY_ID_VALUE, subcategoryId);
    transformer.setParameter(GOOD, good);
    transformer.setParameter(VALIDATOR, validatorXslGood);

    transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(outWriter));
```

but

> The first argument to the non-static Java function 'validateGood' is not a valid object reference.
>   Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'boolean'.

Can you explain me what wrong?

UPD:

ValidatorXslGood.java code:

```
public class ValidatorXslGood {

private Good good;

private Map<String, String> setErrors;
private ResourceBundleManager errorManager;

public ValidatorXslGood() {
    errorManager = new ResourceBundleManager();
    errorManager.setResourceBundle(RESOURCE_BUNDLE__FOR_ERROR_FILE);
}

public Good getGood() {
    return good;
}

public void setGood(Good good) {
    this.good = good;
}

public boolean validateGood(Good good) {
    if (checkingName(good.getName())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

I try create  validator  in XSL

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:good="xalan://com.epam.laba.model.Good"
xmlns:validator="xalan://com.epam.laba.validator.ValidatorXslGood"
    extension-element-prefixes="validator" >

    <xsl:include href="parameter.xsl"/>
    <xsl:variable name="validatorConstructor" select="validator:new()"/>
    <xsl:param name="validator"/>
    <xsl:param name="good"/>
```

........

but i have new error and i can't understand where error in path

> Cannot find class 'com.epam.laba.validator.ValidatorXslGood'. Cannot
>   find external constructor 'com.epam.laba.validator.ValidatorXslGood'.

Comment: Please show us `validateGood` implementation, or at least, its signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you miss the syntax. [Here](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ext-func-calls) it is stated that the syntax should be *prefix:methodName(object, args)*, where *prefix* is the extension namespace prefix (which you need to declare as *xmlns:prefix="URI" extension-element-prefixes="prefix ..."*) and *methodName* is the name of the instance method to invoke on *object* with the *args* arguments.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:validator="xalan://com.epam.laba.parser.validator.ValidatorXslGood"
     extension-element-prefixes="validator" ... >

<xsl:param name="validator"/> <!-- That is in reality validatorObject -->
<xsl:param name="good"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/|node()|@*">
    <xsl:if test="validator:validateGood($validator, $good)">
...
```

Comment: headpost... That is in reality validatorObject, but it doesn't work i create object in xsl

Comment: Does it work, if you create an object in Java (outside XSL)? Concerning your update: (1) check that `ValidatorXslGood#ValidatorXslGood()` constructor is not throwing runtime exception (2) check that Xalan can access the class, i.e. in application server environment it **should** be packaged with your application (and not in `server/libs`) so first check that above code works for standalone application / Unit test. If everything fails, provide also the stack trace.